# How to format JSon for Jquery's Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm writting an Autocomplete field using RoR and Jquery.

When I call `getJson`:

```
var aeropuertos;
    $.getJSON('web_services/get_airports', function(data) {
        aeropuertos = data;
    });

    $("#airports_input_origen").autocomplete({source:aeropuertos});
    $("#airports_input_destino").autocomplete({source:aeropuertos});
```

I get this:

```
[
    [
        "(GKA)",
        "GOROKA",
        "GOROKA",
        "PAPUA NEW GUINEA"
    ],
    [
        "(LAE)",
        "LAE",
        "PAPUA NEW GUINEA",
        "00"
    ],
    [
        "(MAG)",
        "MADANG",
        "MADANG",
        "PAPUA NEW GUINEA"
    ],
    [
        "(HGU)",
        "MOUNT HAGEN",
        "MOUNT HAGEN",
        "PAPUA NEW GUINEA"
    ],
    [
        "(LAE)",
        "NADZAB",
        "NADZAB",
        "PAPUA NEW GUINEA"
    ]
]
```

But it seems that the format isn't right since the autocomplete is not working and is throwing this error:

> this.source is not a function

**----------------- SOLVED --------------**

It was a JSON format Issue!

Instead of sending [ ["", "" , ...] , ... ]

I had to send: [ "......." , ".........", ....]

(solution: [Create JSON of one dimension Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550022/create-json-of-one-dimension-ruby/6550142#6550142))

Thx anyway for your time! =)

Comment: are you using jqueryUi autocomplete?

Comment: It might not be _just_ the JSON that's problematic. After the `$.getJSON` call is there other code that depends on `aeropuertos` being set to `data`? If so, that won't work because the ajax call is asychronous. The solution would be to move the dependent code into the `$.getJSON` callback.

Comment: Yes, I'm using jqueryUI Autocomplete.

Comment: @content01 -- try answering your own question, rather than editing your question. Then, once time elapses, accept that as the correct answer

Comment: @Jesse, I can't... I don't have enough reputation for that.