# Create JSON of one dimension Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I want to have this:

> ["(GKA) GOROKA, GOROKA, PAPUA NEW
>   GUINEA"]

instead of:

> [
>       [
>           "(GKA)",
>           "GOROKA",
>           "GOROKA",
>           "PAPUA NEW GUINEA"
>       ] ]

I have this code so far:

```
@aeropuertos = ""
    f = File.open("./public/aeropuertos/aeropuertos.cvs", "r")
    f.each_line { |line|
      fields = line.split(':')

      if (fields[2] == "N/A")
        @line =  "(" << fields[1] << ")" << ",," << fields[3] << "," << fields[4]
      else
        @line =  "(" << fields[1] << ")"  << "," << fields[2] << "," << fields[3] << "," << fields[4]
      end
      @aeropuertos += @line << "\n"
    }
    return CSV.parse(@aeropuertos).to_json
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why are you splitting the CSV by-hand only to build a new CSV string which will then be parsed by CSV.parse?

Answer (score 1):

@aeropuertos = ""

```
f = File.open("./public/aeropuertos/aeropuertos.cvs", "r")
f.each_line { |line|
  fields = line.split(':')

  if (fields[2] == "N/A")
    @line =  "(" << fields[1] << ")" << ",," << fields[3] << "," << fields[4]
  else
    @line =  "(" << fields[1] << ")"  << "," << fields[2] << "," << fields[3] << "," << fields[4]
  end
  @aeropuertos += @line << "\n"
}
res = []
CSV.parse(@aeropuertos).each do |c|
    res << c.join(',')
end
return res.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the CSV parser. Just create the structure you want as you read each line. That is, instead of making a large string in `@aeropuertos` and parsing it with a CSV parser, make `@aeropuertos` an array, and add each `@line` to the array.

So, instead of this:

```
@aeropuertos += @line << "\n"
```

Do this:

```
@aeropuertos << @line
```

But be sure to say this at the beginning:

```
@aeropuertos = []
```